# Proving a function has a bijection

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Can someone give me an example of a bijective function f: A → B with two finite sets? Suppose A = {1, 2, 3, 4} and B = {a, b, c, d}. Can you prove that it is injective and surjective?

Comment: Let $f(1)=a,\,f(2)=b,\,f(3)=c,\,f(4)=d$.  It is injective because no value in $B$ is hit twice, it is surjective because each value in $B$ is hit at least once.

Answer (score 1):

$A = \{1\}, B = \{a\}, f: A \rightarrow B$ defined as $f(1) = a$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $ A = \{ 1 \} $ and $ B = \{ 2 \} $, and define $ f : A \to B $ by $ f(1) = 2 $.

Now, if you meant $ |A| \neq |B| $ when you said $ A \neq B $, then this is impossible, as two sets have the same cardinality if there is a bijection between them.